# Can I change a segue identifier depending on another segue identifier, in code?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller

Can I change a segue identifier depending on what another segue identifier is in code? I'm not even sure if that is the correct question for what I am looking to do.

I have a `ViewController` which has a number of buttons on it. 
Each button has a segue to another `ViewController` which contains some labels, images and buttons. 
The text/images/titles of these labels, images and buttons are determined by which segue (which button on the previous ViewController) is pressed. This is done by giving each property a variable in the initial ViewController and assigning that variable in the 2nd ViewController.
eg. (I will not individually put the .h and .m but just under one heading!)
**1st ViewController:**

```
-(void) prepareForSegue: (UIStoryboardSegue*)segue sender:(id)sender{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"someSegIdentifier"]){
        2ndViewController *aVC = (2ndViewController *)(segue.destinationViewController);
        aVC.TitleString = @"A Title";
        aVC.FImg = [UIImage imageNamed:@"someimage.jpg";
        aVC.Button1String = @"Button 1 Text";
        aVC.Button2String = @"Button 2 Text";
        etc...
} }
```

**2nd View Controller:**

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIImage *FImg;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *TitleString;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *Button1String;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *Button2String;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *TitleLabel;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *FImageView;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *Button1;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *Button2;


-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    self.TitleLabel.text = self.TitleString;
    self.FImageView.image = self.FImg;
    [self.Button1 setTitle:self.Button1String forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.Button2 setTitle:self.Button2String forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

From this ViewController, each button links to another ViewController each (which have NavControllers Embeded), these 2 ViewControllers also have 2 buttons which individually link to a tableViewController. The data displayed in the tableView is determined by the segue ID from the previous 2 viewControllers.

I believe I need to repeat the first process (the code above) on the second set of viewControllers but at the same time change the segue ID for proceeding/destination viewController, so that the tableView can load the correct data. How can I change this Identifier?

I think a hierarchy may be and easier way of explaining it.
[image: Hierarchy]

How would I go about changing the specific segue Identifiers depending on what the previous ViewController shows. Keeping in mind, that for each level their are many different 'links' or specified properties.

Comment: In your hierarchy, say you have viewController A and B in the third row. I see they can both go to the tableViewController, but do you want it to go the other way too? For instance, if I load the tableVC from A, do you want an option to go to back to B as well?

Comment: @AlexJ
No, not really because each of A and B have navigation controllers individually. They are kind of separate entity's under the the ViewController in the second row. I would rather that they just go back to the second row viewController and then choose to go to B from there.

Comment: In that case, couldn't you just call [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES]? Or if you need to do something specific in the segue, you could have a variable in your 3rd ViewController to identify your previous ViewController, and then do an if statement in the segue

Answer (score 0):

You could, instead of sending the information from previous controllers through the segue identifier, create properties on the destination view controllers and change those properties at the time of segue TO that view controller according to the button pressed ( or segue identifier). Then, when there is a segue FROM the view controller, you use those properties and the segue identifier as parameters, instead of just the segue identifier.

e.g.:

if you go are going from controller A to B to C, and there are 3 possible segues from A to B and 3 possible segues from B to C, you could have a `NSString` property in B which would go like

```
in A:
-(void) prepareForSegue: (UIStoryboardSegue*)segue sender:(id)sender{
   if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"identifier1"]){
        2ndViewController *aVC = (2ndViewController *)(segue.destinationViewController);
        aVC.propertyIWasTalkingAbout = "segue1"
   }
   else if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"identifier2"]){
        2ndViewController *aVC = (2ndViewController *)(segue.destinationViewController);
        aVC.propertyIWasTalkingAbout = "segue2"
   }
   else if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"identifier3"]){
        2ndViewController *aVC = (2ndViewController *)(segue.destinationViewController);
        aVC.propertyIWasTalkingAbout = "segue3"
   }
}
```

in B:

```
-(void) prepareForSegue: (UIStoryboardSegue*)segue sender:(id)sender{
   if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"identifier4"]){
        switch (self.propertyIWasTalkingAbout){
             case("segue1"):
             //...
             break;
             case("segue2"):
             //...
             break;
             case("segue3"):
             //...
             break;
        }

   }
   else if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"identifier5"]){
switch (self.propertyIWasTalkingAbout){
             case("segue1"):
             //...
             break;
             case("segue2"):
             //...
             break;
             case("segue3"):
             //...
             break;
        }
   }
   else if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"identifier6"]){
        switch (self.propertyIWasTalkingAbout){
             case("segue1"):
             //...
             break;
             case("segue2"):
             //...
             break;
             case("segue3"):
             //...
             break;
        }
   }
}
```

I wrote all this code here, not on XCode, so there might be some errors, but I hope you get the idea, and I also hope I got what you meant :p

Answer (score 0):

Yes you are definitely asking the wrong question. You are creating a segue for each button? 
That is the wrong approach as segue are meant to be between 2 view controllers.
if you had 100 button would you create 100 segues?
In your case you have 2 controllers so it should be only one segue.

If you need to know which button was pressed I suggest you to give the sender a tag number and check it when preparing to segue.